# how can I convert input json to an array in node.js?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

In my code I have a function that takes a json as an input:

```
[{
    "location": {},
    "_id": "5852d6fe29a15b4e6f9fc69d"
}, {
    "location": {},
    "_id": "5852d71529a15b4e6f9fc69e"
}, {
    "location": {},
    "_id": "5852d73229a15b4e6f9fc69f"
}, {
    "location": {},
    "_id": "5852d75b29a15b4e6f9fc6a0"
}]
```

I need to convert it so that the result is an array:

```
["5852d6fe29a15b4e6f9fc69d", "5852d6fe29a15b4e6f9fc69d",
 "5852d73229a15b4e6f9fc69f", "5852d75b29a15b4e6f9fc6a0"]
```

This json is a parameter to my function, basically the block code looks like this:

```
function parseJson(inputJson) {   
    if (inputJson!= undefined) {
        var outputArray = 
    }
}
```

what's the best way to parse that data?

Comment: simply use map function

Comment: I'll bet you dollars to doughnuts that the input *isn't* JSON. JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON. (What's quoted at the top of the question would be invalid if it were JSON. For that matter, it's invalid as JavaScript, too.)

Comment: Are you asking about parsing JSON or converting an array of objects into an array of numbers? I suspect you mean the latter and just don't understand what parsing means or what JSON is.

Comment: Your first code block is neither valid JSON nor valid JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
var json = [{"location": {}, "_id": "5852d6fe29a15b4e6f9fc69d"}, {"location": {}, "_id": "5852d71529a15b4e6f9fc69e"}, {"location": {}, "_id": "5852d73229a15b4e6f9fc69f"}, {"location": {}, "_id": "5852d75b29a15b4e6f9fc6a0"}],
    arr = json.map(item => item._id);

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Code dumps are not *useful* answers. *(not my dv)*

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I help with code example, description and also a link pointing to the used method. Thanks for your comment

Answer (score -1):

You can use Array.prototype.map

```
let myJSON = [
    { location: {}, _id: 5852d6fe29a15b4e6f9fc69d },
    { location: {}, _id: 5852d71529a15b4e6f9fc69e },
    { location: {}, _id: 5852d73229a15b4e6f9fc69f },
    { location: {}, _id: 5852d75b29a15b4e6f9fc6a0 }
];
let myArray = myJSON.map(obj => obj._id);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method to transform an array into another array using a mapping function:

```js
var oldArray = [ { "location": {}, "_id": "5852d6fe29a15b4e6f9fc69d" },
  { "location": {}, "_id": "5852d71529a15b4e6f9fc69e" },
  { "location": {}, "_id": "5852d73229a15b4e6f9fc69f" },
  { "location": {}, "_id": "5852d75b29a15b4e6f9fc6a0" } ];


var newArray = oldArray.map(function(element){
  return element._id;
});//map()

console.log( newArray );
```